# jPlayer Playlist with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am using a jPlayer playlist and need help to add Google Analytic events to show which song has been played by pushing the play button, clicking the title in the playlist, next 
or prev, or as it advances at the end of a song. I have tried to reference the player by the ID as stated in the API reference but my console logs don't show up. To be clear, I have cleaned this code up to not show my real titles and URL's

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [
    {
        title:"<Title Here>",

                    m4v: "<Link Here>",
        poster:" <Link Here> "
    },
           { 
        title:"<Title Here>",

                    m4v: " <Link Here> ",
        poster:" <Link Here> "
    },
    {
        title:" <Title Here> ",
        m4v: " <Link Here> ",
        poster: " <Link Here> "
    }
], {
    swfPath: "js",
                                 solution:"flash, html",
    supplied: "m4v "
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function() {
        console.log('here');
    },
    ended: function() {
        console.log('here');
    }
});
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The event handlers should be supplied in the jPlayerPlaylist constructor's third parameter along with "swfPath" etc.  So in your example, the following should work (I've refactored the playlist parameter into a separate variable to neaten the code somewhat):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var playlist = [
    {title: "<Title Here>", m4v: "<Link Here>", poster: "<Link Here>"},
    {title: "<Title Here>", m4v: "<Link Here>", poster: "<Link Here>"},
    {title: "<Title Here>", m4v: "<Link Here>", poster: "<Link Here>"}
  ];

  var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
  }, playlist, {
    swfPath: "js",
    solution:"flash, html",
    supplied: "m4v",
    ready: function() {
      console.log('here');
    },
    ended: function() {
      console.log('here');
    }
  });
});
```